# Add Title and Icon images to QProgressDialog

Tags: qt, progressdialog

I am trying to change the default QProgressDialog to show the status of update:

```
 ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()),  SIGNAL(progressValue(int)),
                                        progressDialog, SLOT(setValue(int)) ) );
 ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()),  SIGNAL(progressText(QString)),
                                        progressDialog, SLOT(setLabelText(QString)) ) );

 //update the packages using the updater
 updater.UpdatePackages();
```

How can I change the default size, add icon image and change the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could make it work by creating your own subclass of QProgressDialog and adding your own SLOTS.
Something like this:

MyQProgressDialog.h

```
class MyQProgressDialog : public QProgressDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
    setTitle(QString title);
    setIcon(QIcon icon);
    setSize(int w, int h);
};
```

MyQProgressDialog.cpp

```
void MyQProgressDialog::setTitle(QString title)
{
    setWindowTitle(title);
}
void MyQProgressDialog::setIcon(QIcon icon)
{
    setWindowIcon(icon)
}
void MyQProgressDialog::(int w, int h)
{
    setFixedSize(w, h);
}
```

And then change your connection with that:

```
ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()), SIGNAL(progressValue(int)), progressDialog, SLOT(setValue(int))));
ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()), SIGNAL(progressText(QString)), progressDialog, SLOT(setLabelText(QString))));
ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()), SIGNAL(progressIcon(QIcon)), progressDialog, SLOT(setIcon(QIcon))));
ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()), SIGNAL(progressSize(int, int)), progressDialog, SLOT(setSize(int, int)));


//update the packages using the updater
updater.UpdatePackages();
```

This include that you create 2 new signals progressIcon(QIcon) and progressSize(int, int) in your updater.

Edit: now that I think of it if you go along this way it may be easier to just create one new slot that take all the things to update, something like that:

```
//MyQProgressDialog.h
class MyQProgressDialog : public QProgressDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
    updateEverything(Int value, QString text, QString title, QIcon icon, Int w, Int h);
};

//MyQProgressDialog.cpp
void MyQProgressDialog::updateEverything(Int value, QString text, QString title, QIcon icon, Int w, Int h)
{
    setWindowTitle(title);
    setWindowIcon(icon);
    setFixedSize(w, h);
    setValue(value);
    setLabelText(text);
}

//Connection
ASSERT( connect( &(updater.GetUpdateInstaller()), SIGNAL(progress(int, QString, QString, QIcon, Int, Int)), progressDialog, SLOT(updateEverything(progress(int, QString, QString, QIcon, Int, Int)));
```

But this means that you can't updrade aspects alone anymore. It can be usefull depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the dialog title by `setWindowTitle()`, setting it's size and it's label. Label can hold a `QString` or a `QPixmap` but not both of them.

```
     QProgressDialog * dialog = new QProgressDialog(this) ;
     // fix dialog height
     dialog->setMinimumHeight(400);
     dialog->setMaximumHeight(400);
     // set dialog title
     dialog->setWindowTitle("Progress Dialog");
     QLabel * labl  = new QLabel(this);
     labl->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/icon.png"));
     labl->setText("text");
     dialog->setLabel(labl);
```

If you need wider flexibility you should subclass a `QDialog` and add a `QProgressBar` alongside every other necessary widgets like `QLablel`s and `QButtonGroup`s.

Comment: This is also a nice answer, but I prefer the other approach since it has more flexibility. Thanks for your answer.